# SQL Server Can you update an element within a table that was created through multiple UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a table made of multiple different tables. I am trying to update a specific element within the large conglomerate table, but am not able to - keep getting syntax errors. Is there a way to update elements within a table made up of multiple tables?

```
WITH sel AS
(
  SELECT MIN(attribute_value) minyear,
         MAX(attribute_value) maxyear
  FROM ais.dms_attributes
  WHERE attribute_name = 'Year'
  AND   ISNUMERIC(attribute_value) = 1
),
rec AS
(
  SELECT CAST(minyear AS INT) minyear
  FROM sel
  UNION ALL
  SELECT (CAST(minyear AS INT) +1) minyear
  FROM rec
  WHERE minyear <(SELECT maxyear FROM sel)
),
allrows AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT -1 ENTITY_ID,
         attribute_value ENTITY_NAME,
         CASE
           WHEN attribute_name = 'tenant' THEN 'TENANT'
           WHEN attribute_name = 'investment' THEN 'INVESTMENT'
           WHEN attribute_name = 'asset' THEN 'ASSET'
           ELSE attribute_name
         END AS ENTITY_TYPE
  FROM a.attributes
  WHERE attribute_name IN ('tenant','investment','asset')
  AND   attribute_value IS NOT NULL
  AND   charindex('[',attribute_value) < 1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT CTYPE ENTITY_ID,
         TYPE ENTITY_NAME,
         'TYPE' ENTITY_TYPE
  FROM a.types 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CGROUP ENTITY_ID,
         GROUP ENTITY_NAME,
         'GROUP' ENTITY_TYPE
  FROM a.group
  UPDATE a.group SET GROUP = 'Legacy' WHERE GROUP = 'Regular'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -1,
         CAST(minyear AS VARCHAR) ENTITY_NAME,
         'YEAR' ENTITY_TYPE
  FROM rec
)
SELECT *
FROM allrows 
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN ENTITY_TYPE = 'YEAR' THEN ENTITY_NAME
         END DESC,
         CASE
           WHEN ENTITY_TYPE <> 'YEAR' THEN ENTITY_NAME
         END
```

Comment: In a word? No. UNION doesn't "make a table", it creates a result set from multiple tables. Update the original value in the underlying table and the union query will reflect the change

Comment: Aside: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).